# Django Rest Framework KeyError 'request'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have my serializer like this

```
class PublicacionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    usuario = UserSerializer2()
    likeado = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Publicacion
        fields = ('id','usuario', 'likeado')

    def get_likeado(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        try:
            like = Like.objects.get(publicacion=obj, usuario=user)
            return like.id
        except Like.DoesNotExist:
            return False
```

so i use that seriaizer in another one:

```
class EstadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publicacion = PublicacionSerializer(read_only=True)
```

in views.py i have

```
class ModificarEstadoMixin(object):
    queryset = Estado.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstadoSerializer

class ModificarEstadoDetail(ModificarEstadoMixin, RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,
              CanModifEstado,)
    pass
```

when i access to the url for know if an user has liked to a post i got a KeyError 'request' in code line

```
user = self.context['request'].user
```

anyone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call that serializer, you have to pass context from view like

```
MySerializer(context={'request': request})
```

Comment: or you can call `get_serializer` method, which will pass context for you

Comment: i don't know where i should to put it @itzmeontv i edited my post

Comment: Hi there. Where I should properly use the `context={'request': request}` using the example posted by the  question? I'm getting NameError: name 'request' is not defined.